Entra External ID - Migration Options
I need to migrate users from an on prem Auth provider, where I am not able to access the passwords (On way hashed) to Entra External ID, Is there away in Entra to valid the user against the on prem auth when signing in and then move the password to Entra external ID, Similar to B2C Custom Policy?Or is there a way to supply the salted password with the salt?

Answer From Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1885622/entra-external-id-migration-options)
Thank you for reaching us!
If I understand correctly, you are looking a way to move the on-premises user's passwords to Entra External ID if this the case, synchronizing the users from on-premises to Microsoft Entra External ID is not possible because there is no feature available in the tenant. This means you cannot directly sync passwords from on-premises to Entra External ID
If you need to migrate users, you might have to manually recreate user accounts and reset their passwords. This can be a time-consuming process and may require users to set new passwords.
Appreciate if you could share the feedback on this, on our feedback community which is closely monitored by our product team
Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries in the comments section.
